# Queries regarding the probability tree

Tags: probability

I'm an undergraduate student taking a Discrete Mathematics Course with weak Statistics background(in particular Probability and Counting). I have this assignment question as follows.

[image]

[image]

I managed to work out (b) with the use of a probability tree to get 0.2225, which is the sum of all 4 branches that involves being late. However, (c) gave me some problem because to find the probability of it raining and arriving late in the numerator of the conditional probability, I realised I have to go through the same 4 branches, and that didn't make sense because clearly, the answer to this conditional probability can't be 1.

Can anyone clarify what have I done wrong here in my calculation or use of probability tree?

Update: It happens that I was careless in concluding previously that it is rainy occurs in 4 branches instead of 2(which apparently is the correct answer). The correct answer for (c) should be 50/89 which is the result of dividing the sum of the 2 branches with the answer found in (b).

PS: Feel free to recommend me some statistics books in the comments section, preferably with good exercise problems with solutions to brush up on my fundamentals. Thanks.

Comment: "to find the probability of it raining and arriving late in the numerator of the conditional probability, I realised I have to go through the same 4 branches, ..."  Aren't there only **two** branches where it rains and you're late?  Please clarify this part of your question.

Comment: @saulspatz Alright this is awkward, you are right that somehow I made a careless mistake and considered all 4 branches. Could you assure me that the correct answer is 50/89?

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth please add the solution in an edit :)